# Drupal 8 - Admin - Content Types - Manage form display - Fields groups, labels, headers

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-themes, drupal-fields, drupal-content-types

I would like to know if possible in ADMIN, without modifying the admin template, by means of some module or extension do the following:

I would need to be able to create the data entry form for content types by putting headers, separation lines between elements, etc., so that field management is better understood.

For example)

**Currently)**

Header - Image
Header - Title
Header - Text

Featured - Title
Featured - Text
Contact Us

**Wanted)**

Headboard
--- Image
--- Title
--- Text

---

Featured Articles
--- Title
--- Text
--- Image

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module for organizing fields like HTML5 elements, Tabs, Accordions, Fieldsets etc.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group